# Two textviews on listview aligend left

Tags: android

I have 2 textviews on my listview that I want to one of them has right align and another align center
but all of them aligend left !!!
my listview xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_subject"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:textSize="20dp"   
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">    

  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="ads"/>

   <TextView 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:id="@+id/tv_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

it is big problem for me,
please help me.

Comment: Why don't you just use relative layout? You can then manually adjust the textviews where ever you want them to be.

Comment: If you do not want to use layout realitives, you must add 2 panels each with android: layout_weight: 1, that divided into 2 equal parts space where you need the blocks in each panel agreagas the form you need, each one you put the alignment you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you set your `android:layout_width` to "match_parent", you should get the effect you are looking for.

Think of it this way:

Your views are always drawn from the top left corner of where they should be in a LinearLayout. If the width is wrap_content, it will make the width wide enough to hold your content, and then align it to the center/right of that area. Since the area is just big enough to hold your content, you can't see a difference.

If the area of your view fills the parent, it will align based on the width of the parent, not just the width of your content.

**Alternative**

If this is unsatisfactory, you can also use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, and set layout_centerHorizontal and layout_alignParentRight to true for the views you want to relocate.

Comment: Typically responses to questions/answers should be in the comments sections. Additional answers are considered answers to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and worked successfully but when I touch a row on ListView it's color not be changed when my finger is on the row because TextView width is Match_Parent.